# Facebook sdk android manage_notifications

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, facebook-sdk-3.1

I want to get user notifications in my app but whenever I try to access them it pops with an error saying that the app needs manage_notifications=true error 403. plz help me how to enable this permission.